# AUTO_INCREMENT current value influenced by manual inserts

Tags: mysql

I just figured an auto_increment behavior which makes total sense, but that I would like to avoid:

A good example is worth a thousand words:

```
create table test(id int not null auto_increment,somecrap text) ENGINE = INNODB;
insert into test(somecrap) values ('a');
insert into test(id,somecrap) values (100000,'b');
insert into test(somecrap) values ('c');
```

Here is the result :

```
╔════════╦══════════╗
║   id   ║ somecrap ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
║      1 ║ a        ║
║ 100000 ║ b        ║
║ 100001 ║ c        ║
╚════════╩══════════╝
```

Here is what I would like to see:

```
╔════════╦══════════╗
║   id   ║ somecrap ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
║      1 ║ a        ║
║ 100000 ║ b        ║
║      2 ║ c        ║
╚════════╩══════════╝
```

Once again, I totally understand why they did this that way...but my question is: **Is there a way to ... kind of "deactivate" this auto increment value update when manually inserting an id ?**

**If no**, is there a good solution to simulate it ?

An asumption you could make: I **KNOW** that my auto increments wont reach 100000 (100k is for the example... the actual use case is a much bigger figure)

Must I run two separate queries like:

```
select max(id) from test where id<100000
```

and then insert with `max(id)+1` ?

Since my transaction isolation level is "read committed", such a behavior will introduce potential concurrency issues => I would like to avoid it if possible !

Comment: Why do you want to insert yourself the number into the INSERT query ?

Comment: In a nutshell, my ids are 64 bits for which the first 20 are the 'item class', and the next are the id among this class.
When inserting into a table without specifying the id, that sets the 'default class' on the record (the auto increment value is intialized to its value+1).

Comment: insert into test(id,somecrap) values (100000,'b'); - this is very bad query, when you are using the table with an autoincrement column. It's code smell

Comment: can you split your id into separate columns?

Comment: As my previous comment to a deleted answer vanished too (a good thing), here from [ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html): *You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to the value that is currently in use. **For both InnoDB and MyISAM, if the value is less than or equal to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value is reset to the current maximum AUTO_INCREMENT column value plus one**.*

Comment: @FuzzyTree nope... that does not allow me to perform joins on an arbitrary set of tables :/
I cant use a classic foreign key approach (an id can be inserted in mutiple tables).

Comment: @VMai That's what I feared :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround, which mimics Oracle sequences:

Just create a 'referential' table which is basically a key-value table, with 'value' being an int.

The equivalent to `mysequence.nextval` would be:

```
UPDATE referential SET value=@newval:=(value+1) 
     WHERE key=/*put your key (class name for me) here*/;
SELECT @newval;
```

Then, the @newval can safely be used as an id.

**Warning** If executed in a transaction, this **prevents** any parallel insert. Thus, this request can be executed outside any transaction, or the 'referential' table may be created as **MyISAM**

Comment: So essentially you stop using an auto increment column, and rather than computing the next id before the insert it's being kept track of in another table?

Comment: @Leeft Yes. Like I would have done using Oracle and its (much more flexible) sequences

Answer (score 1):

If you need the ID after the insert, it's better to find it with a SELECT query and WHERE clauses.

**It's a really bad idea !!! but :**

You can use the ALTER TABLE. **EDIT : This works only with MySQL 5.6 !**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = ...;
```

[Read the mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: someone already proposed this answer (but has unfortunatly deleted it) ... this does not work when setting the id to a lower value than the column max. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc080a/1) that [VMai](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3501730/vmai) made

Comment: ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = ...; - it's will not be work. This query will be success but increment value won't changed

Comment: Yes, the query works with MySQL 5.6. [This fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc080/1)

Comment: @Alexis_user You're right ! you got my upvote. However, that does not solve the issue: I must run 3 requests to do so: 1) select the current auto-increment value 2) insert 3) alter table.
That's 3 potential conccurency issues :(
Moreover, the alter table is commiting my transaction, isnt it ?

Comment: Yes but you want to do an unusual thing... AUTOINCREMENT are not built for that. I thing you have to do differently.

Comment: @Alexis_user I think so as well =(  ... an Oracle sequence would have solved that !

Answer (score 1):

Even if you got this to work reliably, it would always be a hack. And indeed, an `ALTER TABLE` (or any other DDL statements) would commit any existing transaction. You should really consider an alternative and cleaner approach instead.

It would be much cleaner to simply add another column (or perhaps two, one for each 32 bits) and populate these with the 64 bit id that you can then set to the value you want. If you need them always populated, then copy the auto increment PK over after the insert. This leaves the auto increment key at rest, doesn't introduce transactional problems and it is not a hack ... at the cost of a slightly larger data storage.

Comment: slightly larger data storage is not an issue... but this forces me to maintain two indexes :(  and my 64 bit column can no longer be my primary key.

Comment: But yea, I agree, splitting it would be my cleaner option. My design issue here is that i'm trying to implement a scheme that is deeply NOT relational with a relational database. +1